# Validation Rule For Salesforce

Tags: validation-rule

I have req as follows :'
There are Two Object Account and Job , Account is having a field Public Logo(Url)
and Job is having a field known as Client Logo flag(checkbox).

Client Logo flag can't be set if there is no URL in the Account's public Logo field.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you have tried so far, to get to a solution? Please read [this document](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting here Account is parent of Job. So your validation will look like

```
AND( ISBLANK(Account__r.Public_Logo__c), Client_Logo__c) // check the field API name
```

Here we are checking on Account Public Logo is blank but Client Logo is true. It will give error.

Comment: Yes currently i am testing all possible scenario.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar then you can accept this answer and close the question.